# Resources about Grands Magasins

Tags: vocabulaire, ressources

I'm looking for vocabulary resources to describe the different parts and internal operation of a "Grand Magasin".

For example, in the image below what should I call the balconies, the glass roof, the central area, the cellars, etc ?
I'd also like to describe things like team structure and inventory management.

[image: grand magasin]

Are there online resources, books, or even documentaries I could use?

Answer (score 1):

*Ressources en français sur les grands magasins* me fait immédiatement penser au roman d'Émile Zola: [Au Bonheur des Dames](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/16852).

Il y a aussi un documentaire qui a été diffusé sur Arte, aujourd'hui disponible uniquement en VOD: [Au bonheur des dames, l'invention du Grand Magasin](https://boutique.arte.tv/detail/invention_du_grand_magasin)

Comment: Je plusqueplusunze pour avoir pensé au Bonheur des dames. Juste pour ajouter *La fabuleuse histoire des grands magasins* de Renée Grimaud.

Answer (score 0):

Je vous propose des livres visuels bilingues. Supposant que votre langue maternelle est l'anglais deux tels ouvrages sont

[1](https://www.amazon.fr/Dictionnaire-Visuel-Fran%C3%A7ais-Anglais/dp/2764410778)

[2](https://www.amazon.fr/French-English-Bilingual-Visual-Dictionary/dp/1465459286/ref=pd_cp_14_1?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=1465459286&pd_rd_r=2a5d6aaa-e44d-11e8-9be1-d764d96024b3&pd_rd_w=5JnVv&pd_rd_wg=Mi9Bd&pf_rd_i=desktop-dp-sims&pf_rd_m=A1X6FK5RDHNB96&pf_rd_p=767bee29-b3dc-4737-bd35-530d818921d9&pf_rd_r=NV633Z56CX87QVXFVKP0&pf_rd_s=desktop-dp-sims&pf_rd_t=40701&psc=1&refRID=NV633Z56CX87QVXFVKP0)

Une autre solution pourrait être un dictionnaire bilingue d'[architecture](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Dictionary-Architecture-Construction-English-Dictionnaire/dp/2743006552)

Troisièmement , vous pouvez consulter linguee et chercher chaque mot individuellement.

P.ex. pour inventory management on voit comme traduction gestion des stocks.

https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/inventory+management.html